# window.open не работает

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-webforms

Создал 2 веб-проекта. Данные из SQL сервера отлично помещаются в датагрид.
Но щелчок (клик) не выполняется, чтобы произошел переход ко второй форме.

Как сказать, он не видит есть линк или нет.

Посмотрите сами, пожалуйста:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="javawinop.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>GridView Popup Window Demo </title>
    <style>
        .btInGrid {
            font:Arial, 12px;
            font-weight:normal; 
            color:#000; 
            padding:2px 5px; 
            background-color:#F6C60F; 
            border:solid 1px #F69E14; border-radius:2px;
            -moz-border-radius:2px; -webkit-border-radius:2px; 
            width: 150px; 
            cursor: pointer;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmGridViewDemo" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView" 
            Font-Names="Arial" 
            Font-Size="0.75em" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CellPadding="3" 
            CellSpacing="0" 
            ForeColor="#333" 
            DataKeyNames="EmpID" 
            runat="server">

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="EmpID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" runat ="server" Text ='<%# Eval("EmpID") %>'>
                            </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Employee Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>


                        <input type="button" 
                            class="btInGrid" value='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>' 
                            onclick='javascript:window.open("WebForm2.aspx?empid=<%# Eval("EmpID") %>" ,
                            "Stone Details","height=200,width=500,status=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no,
                            menubar=no,location=center,scrollbars=no,resizable=no")' />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Designation">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesig" runat ="server" 
                            Text ='<%# Eval("Designation") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо input button использовать ссылку (тег a).

Comment: спасибо за вниманию но мне нужн открыт 2 - й форм как messagebox в winform

Comment: ребята я создал етот маленкий переход

Comment: <input type="button"  class="btInGrid" value='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>' 
     onclick="window.open('WebForm2.aspx','_blank','Heigth=300,width=300,left=400')" />

Comment: он работает 
открывает Webform2

но как с этим скриптом как я могу передат параметры?

Comment: empid=<%# Eval("EmpID") %>

Comment: на Webform2? 

и еше Webform2 открывается у меня правый нижный угол а как я могу открыт левый вверх?